# Maximum match for String

Tags: java, string, optimization

I am trying to write a method which will return me a code corresponding to a bank product which I need to pass to a web service. I have an array of eligible *generic* types of products and the input will be a string which will be a specific type of any of the generic types in the array. Let me explain this via the code I already have :

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   String[] names = { "Checking", "Savings", "DEMAT", "DEMAT Savings", "Interest Checking" };
   String input = "Employee Checking";
   int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
   String maxMatch = null;
   for(String name : names) 
   {
      int i = input.indexOf(name);
      if(i > -1 && i < min) 
      {
         min = i;
         maxMatch = name;
      }
   }
   if(null != maxMatch)
   {
      System.out.println("Maximum match for " + input + " found at " + maxMatch);
   }
}
```

The above snippet tries to perform a maximum match for the input. So, if I have "Employee Interest Checking" as input, I get match at "Interest Checking" and not just "Checking".

What I want to know is whether is there any way to optimize this snippet further or are there any cases where this code will fail?

Comment: If the possible matches in names[] were ordered by length, e.g. "Interest Checking" came before "Checking", you wouldn't have to do the comparison to min.  The longer matches would automatically happen first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep sorted array by string length, you can be sure that first match would give the max match

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MaxIndex {

private static String[] names = { "Checking", "Savings", "DEMAT", "DEMAT Savings",
        "Interest Checking","Savings Interest Checking","My Employee Savings Interest Checking" };

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Arrays.sort(names, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            Integer L1 = o1.length();
            return L1.compareTo(o2.length())*-1;
        }
    });

    findMaxMatch("Employee Checking");
    findMaxMatch("Employee Savings");
    findMaxMatch("Employee Interest Checking");
    findMaxMatch("Employee Savings Interest Checking");
    findMaxMatch("My Employee Savings Interest Checking");
    findMaxMatch("Employee Current");
}

private static void findMaxMatch(String input) {
    String maxMatch = maxMatch(input);
    if (null != maxMatch) {
        System.out.println("Maximum match for '" + input + "' found at '"
                + maxMatch+"'");
    }else{
        System.out.println("No match for '"+input+"'");
    }
}

private static String maxMatch(String input) {
    for (String name : names) {
        int i = input.indexOf(name);
        if (i > -1) {
            return name;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

**Output**

```
Maximum match for 'Employee Checking' found at 'Checking'
Maximum match for 'Employee Savings' found at 'Savings'
Maximum match for 'Employee Interest Checking' found at 'Interest Checking'
Maximum match for 'Employee Savings Interest Checking' found at 'Savings Interest Checking'
Maximum match for 'My Employee Savings Interest Checking' found at 'My Employee Savings Interest Checking'
No match for 'Employee Current'
```

Comment: It might be an overhead if you sort it every time you find a match, but if you sort it once and refer to sorted array, then it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you want to find the longest match in case there are several matches.  One way to do it would be to sort your "names" in descending order (based on their length) and stop at the first match.

You can do this by using a *SortedMap<Integer,String>* in which you'd put the length of every "name" from your "names" as its key.

For example by doing something like this:

```
SortedMap<Integer,String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>( new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return -o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
for ( final String name: names ) {
    map.put(name.length(),name);
}
```

You then iterate and stop as soon as you find the first match.

It's kinda "overkill" but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This would fail if the max match was not at the first part of the string.  If for instance, your input was `Interest Checking For Employees` it would match `Checking` instead of `Interest Checking`.  Is max match supposed to find the account with the most sequential characters that match?  Or just the match closest to the end of the input?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the found string sould always be a substring of the query?

Use `contains()` to find a substring, and if found, keep it if it is the longest yet.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String[] names = {"Checking", "Savings", "DEMAT", "DEMAT Savings", "Interest Checking"};
    String input = "Employee Interest Checking";
    int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    String maxMatch = null;
    for (String name : names)
    {
        boolean has = input.contains(name);
        if (has && min < name.length())
        {
            min = name.length();
            maxMatch = name;
        }
    }
    if (null != maxMatch)
    {
        System.out.println("Maximum match for " + input + " found at " + maxMatch);
    }
}
```

and just as user988052 said; if you order the array in the right way you can stop at the first match so you don't have to search anymore and can eliminate `min`.

Ordering the array descending by length:

```
    Arrays.sort(names, new Comparator<String>()
    {
        public int compare(String o1, String o2)
        {
            int d = o2.length() - o1.length();
            return d != 0? d : ((Comparable<String>)o1).compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

use this for finding last position

```
names.lastIndexOf(input)
```

based on array position, get the value